# New Installation of SilverStripe 4 InjectorNotFoundException

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm using Vagrant/Homestead/Virtualbox ~ Vagrant version 2.2.10 | Homestead 10.1.1 | Virtualbox 5.2

I'm running the SilverStripe installation on PHP7.4 and my PHP CLI version is also PHP7.4

Following the SilverStripe [installation instructions](https://www.silverstripe.org/download/) I've ran the following:

```
composer create-project silverstripe/installer client-folder
```

When I load up my installation for the first time I get the following error: (I've censored out the client's name)
[image]

Weirdly, even though install.php is no longer included with the installed, I got an old install.php file and ran it and the install.php page loaded up perfectly. When I then ran the install script it gave me the error above again.

I've gone through and made sure all the required extensions are installed.

Could anyone advise on how to fix this please?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look at this. I tried to destroy my vagrant box using the 'vagrant destroy' command but it didn't work.

I ended up opening up the Virtual Box UI and I then destroyed my Vagrant local machine using that interface.

Afterwards, I ran Vagrant Up to create the 'new' box for the 'first time'.

Silverstripe now loads up perfectly well. As a side, Laravel also didn't work and now works.

In short, it was a problem with my local machine and not SilverStripe.